# Firefox "media emulate print" vs print this page

Tags: css, firefox, printing, emulation, print-preview

I've got some trouble printing a web page in Firefox. If I use **media emulate print** in the console the CSS look great. But if I look at the print preview via **menu -> print this page**.

It looks horrible and also only the first page is shown - further pages are empty!

So does anybody know the difference between **media emulate print** and **menu -> print this page**?

How I can solve my problem?

Comment: Also, "media emulate print" doesn't emulate page break behavior, which is one of the big differences between print and screen media.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Firefox bug. It’s documented here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1448507

The workaround is to move your CSS to the `web_accessible_resources` section of your manifest, and then insert a link to it into your head element using JavaScript. You can refer to it using the `browser.runtime.getURL()` method.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getURL